# Best way to store imported data in variables

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, storing-data

I'm creating an application in Unity where I import a JSON database from the web at runtime and display the info in a AR environment.

I've firstly created a storage class named "Collezione" (Collection in Italian) for that porpuse only as I tried to keep everything as organized as possible.
The collection has a name and a list of showcases, each one with an identifier and a list of objects:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collezione : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string nome;
    public List<Vetrina> collezione;
}

public class Vetrina
{
    public string nome;
    public List<ObjectClass> vetrina;
}

public class ObjectClass
{
    public string id;
    public Vector3 posizione;
    public string denominazione;
    public string materiale;
    public string forma;
    public string cronologia;
    public string da;
    public string a;
}
```

Since it's a MonoBehaviour class, I need to attach it to an object and instantiate its reference in every other script. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. I tried to convert it in a static class and it seems to work, but I wanted to know if there is a better solution.
Here is the static version.

```
public static class Collezione
{
    public static string nome;
    public static List<Vetrina> collezione;
}

public class Vetrina
{
    public string nome;
    public List<ObjectClass> vetrina;
}

public class ObjectClass
{
    public string id;
    public Vector3 posizione;
    public string denominazione;
    public string materiale;
    public string forma;
    public string cronologia;
    public string da;
    public string a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of your *Collection* consumers, I'd say that the most clean way to provide them one is to use dependency injection. But both of your examples are okay, since dependency injection is not something trivial to achieve in Unity. The static class approach might be a little better, since when you use *GetComponent* all over your other scripts, it's slightly harder to test.

So if you want to go for dependency injection, you would need some component, responsible for just composing other components and injecting their dependencies. Without using any DI container framework that will be a little tricky, but still.

First you might introduce an interface to easily find your components, that would need your *Collection*:

```cs
public interface IConsumatoreDelCollezione
{
    public Collezione Collezione { get; set; }
}
```

Just make all the components that would need your *Collection* implement that interface, including the one that stores data into *Collection*. So that component would store data, other read.

The actual implementation of your *Collection* does not matter. It could be a *MonoBehaviour* or a *ScriptableObject*. But the best for testing would be just a normal C# object. And your *MonoBehaviour* component would just wrap that object. For example like this:

```cs
public class CollezioneComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collezione collezione;

    public void Awake()
    {
        name = "ContenitoreDelCollezione"; // To easily find the container.
    }
}
```

And than you need some *CompositionRoot* to wire this all together automatically:

```cs
public class CompositionRoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Awake()
    {
        var contenitore = Find("ContenitoreDelCollezione").GetComponent<CollezioneComponent>();

        var tutti = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        foreach (var obj in tutti)
        {
            var consumatori = obj.GetComponents<IConsumatoreDelCollezione>();
            foreach (var consumatore in consumatori)
            {
                consumatore.Collezione = contenitore.collezione;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is that you should not use *Collection* during *Awake* event in your consumers, since it might not be injected yet. Use it in *Start* at least and so on.

Also all that might be easier to achieve with a DI container framework, such as Zenject for example. So you can take a look at this one.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I think I'll go for the static solution, cause conceptually more suitable for the purpose, since you said it's correct.
I tried to use interface to do something similar with the same collection in a winform app in order to reference the collection between a displaying window and the ones dedicated to editing the data, but I couldn't understand how it works.

Comment: This is in no way better than the `static` solution ;) also it is not guaranteed in which order the two `Awake` calls will be made ... Even **if** you take this route .. why not simply reference the `FindObjectOfType<CollezioneComponent>().collezione` in every class that needs it?

Comment: Dependency injection is preferable over static class or service locator anti-pattern, that you've mentioned, since it helps implementing loosely coupled components, unit testing and improves maintainability of your project. **BUT**. DI makes most sense, when you extensively use it. But of course extensively using DI means moving your entire project to use this pattern. Which certainly might not make much sense, especially for a small Unity project. So you either start your new project with DI, or you've got lots of trouble maintaining your project and decided to switch to DI.